# When to Stop Using L'Hôpital's Rule

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives

I don't understand something about L'Hôpital's rule. In this case:

$$
\begin{align}
& {{}\phantom{=}}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1-x^2}{x^4+x^3+x^2} \\[8pt]
& =\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(e^x-1-x^2)'}{(x^4+x^3+x^2)'} \\[8pt]
& =\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(e^x-2x)'}{(4x^3+3x^2+2x)'} \\[8pt]
& =\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(e^x-2)'}{(12x^2+6x+2)'} \\[8pt]
& = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{(e^x)'}{(24x+6)'} \\[8pt]
& = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x}{24} \\[8pt]
& = \frac{e^0}{24} \\[8pt]
& = \frac{1}{24}
\end{align}
$$

Why do we have to keep on solving after this step:

$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{(e^x-2)'}{(12x^2+6x+2)'}$$

Can't I just plug in $x=0$ and compute the limit at this step giving me:

$$\dfrac{1-2}{0+0+2}=-\dfrac{1}{2}$$

I'm very confused, because I get different probable answers for the limit, depending on when do I stop to differentiate, as clearly $-\frac1{2}\neq \frac 1{24}$.

Comment: You ought to stop already at $\frac{e^x-2x}{4x^3+3x^2+2x}$, which gets you to $\frac{1}{0}$. The limit doesn't exist.

Comment: it has to be 0/0 or infinity/infinity to use L'hopital per iteration

Comment: Please make your question self-contained. At present it is not since to get crucial information requires going to an offsite (and possibly transient) page.

Comment: You're missing "$\lim\limits_{x\to0}$" in front of your third fraction on the first line.  Without that, the "$=$" just before that is not true.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Do you mean that teacher is wrong saying that answer is 1/2?

Comment: After each derivative calculation, *stop and look.* Perhaps the limit can be read off. Perhaps you can do some manipulation to simplify the two expressions.

Comment: You should stop using L'Hôpital's rule if you feel dizziness, if it begins to interfere with your relationships with other mathematicians, or if you find yourself obsessively thinking about how to apply L'Hôpital's rule to objects in your environment, such as your cat.

Comment: Are you sure you typed the question correctly?  It seems more natural for the numerator to be $e^x - 1 - x$ instead of $e^x - 1 - x^2$.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Once your answer is no longer in the form 0/0 or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ you must stop applying the rule. You only apply the rule to attempt to get rid of the indeterminate forms. If you apply L'Hopital's rule when it is not applicable (i.e., when your function no longer yields an indeterminate value of 0/0 or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$) you will most likely get the wrong answer.

You should have stopped differentiating the top and bottom once you got to this:

$\dfrac{e^x-2x}{4x^2+3x^2+2x}$. Taking the limit at that gives you $1/0$. The limit is nonexistent.

Also, don't be tempted to say "infinity" when you see a 0 in the denominator and a non-zero number in the top. It may not be the case. For example, the function $\frac{1}{x}$ approaches infinity and negative infinity from both sides of the limit as x approaches 0. Its not necessarily infinite; its best just to leave it as "nonexistent".

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase: the two-sided limit does not exist. We can say that the one sided limit 0+ is infinite, and the other is negative infinite.

Comment: What I meant to say is this: what is your logic in saying that positive infinity equals negative infinity? It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Sorry, I have reread the Johnson-Freyd comment, and he says that +inf is identical to -inf indeed, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10124/the-factorial-of-1-2-3#comment354984_137634 So, I do not take your argument that you cannot write answer =∞ neither the premice that left limit ≠ right limit.

Comment: @Val, it depends. If you are adding two infinities, $+\infty$ and $-\infty$, to the reals, which is the usual approach in analysis, then those two are utterly different. If you're only adding one infinity, $\infty$, as is sometimes done in, say, topology, then it is what it is. The qestion is whether you want something that goes *up* forever to have the same limite as something that goes *down* forever.

Comment: But what about this case? Why do we assume that we do not want them to be equal and why we cannot call that infinity if it is infinity (whether it is plus or minus)?

Comment: @Val Saying a limit infinity is **qualitative** information, in this case of the behaviour of the function near the point. The difference is between saying "*its values go indefinitely far from the origin*", $\lim=\infty$, to saying "*its values go indefinitely far from the origin in the negative direction*", $-\infty$, (or "*in the positive direction*", $+\infty$)". It is less information. In this case may not be important at all. On the other hand, having more information allows you to use the result if you need to do other stuff with it.

Comment: For example, what *dfeuer* was telling you about is related to this: You can say $\lim_{\rightarrow0}-1/x^2=\infty$. But then that information doesn't help you to compute $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}(f(x)-1/x^2)$, even if you are told that $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)=-\infty$.

Comment: I have this very silly doubt,
I can't find a supporting question but is it legal to simplify limit in between L'Hospital application?
Suppose an intermediate step satisfies the 0/0 condition but its also possible to factor out x from both numerator and denominator and cancel it. My question is the factor and cancel legal?

Answer (score 27):

After differentiating just once, you get $$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{e^x-2x}{4x^3+3x^2+2x}$$ which "evaluates" to $\dfrac 10$, i.e., the numerator approaches $1$, and the denominator approaches $0$. Hence, L'Hopital **no longer applies** and we have $$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{e^x-2x}{4x^3+3x^2+2x}\quad\text{does not exist}.$$

[L'Hopital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) applies *provided and only while* a limit evaluates to an "indeterminate" form: e.g., $\dfrac 00, \;\text{or}\;\dfrac {\pm\infty}{\pm\infty}$.

Comment: Lets make it an even 20 TU's! :-) +1

Comment: What if the numerator is positive infinity and the denominator is negative infinity?

Comment: Isn't 1/0 also indeterminate form?

Comment: No, it is not an indeterminate form, if you mean something like $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac 1{0}$; then we say the limit approaches infinity.

Answer (score 16):

A quick addition to Ra1nMaster's otherwise excellent answer: you can only apply L'Hopital's rule if you have an indeterminate form *and if the limit, after applying L'Hopital's rule, exists.*

This second condition is equally important; for instance a classic stumper is
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{x+\sin x}.$$
Since this limit has the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, one might naively apply L'hopital's rule, getting
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{1+\cos x}$$
and concluding the original limit does not exist. This is wrong;
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{x+\sin x} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{1+\frac{\sin x}{x}}=1.$$

Comment: Inspired me +1 !

Comment: This explains subtle details. +1!

Comment: The method used by the top answers seem to be wrong, based on this.

Answer (score 9):

One must be very careful about using l'Hospital's rule.  It applies only when the numerator and denominator both tend to $0$ or $\infty$ and the denominator is never $0$ in a punctured neighborhood of the point.  A denominator of the form $x\sin \frac1x$ is ineligable for the rule.

But, students should try to avoid the rule anyway.  Here is a parable.  A student is assigned the task of finding

$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin^6 x}{x^6}.
$$

A bad student cancels the $6$ and the $x$ giving $\sin$.

A naive student applies l'Hospital's rule 6 times and eventually gets $\frac{720}{720} = 1$.

A mediocre student applies the rule once, and gets

$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{6\sin^5 x \cos x}{6x^5}.
$$

He cancels the $6$, and removes the $\cos x$ term since it tends to $1$.  He repeats the process 5 more times.

A good student writes the expression as:

$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \left[\frac{\sin x}{x}\right]^6.
$$

He uses continuity of $t^6$ to move the limit inside the brackets and gets $1^6 = 1$.

An engineer says "$\sin x = x$, so the expression is $1$."  And, he'd be right!

---

Using l'Hospital's rule can also hurt the students understanding of a problem.  Here's a classic example.

The $p$-power mean of two positive numbers, $x$ and $y$ is defined as:

$$
M_p(x,y) = \left[\frac{x^p + y^p}{p}\right]^{\frac1p}.
$$

Can one provide suggestive evidence without using l'Hospital's rule that

$$
\lim_{p\to0^{+}} M_p(x,y) = \sqrt{xy}?
$$

One way to do this is to use the approximation $x^p \approx 1 + p \log x$ for $p$ small, taken from the Taylor expansion of $x^p$ at $p=0$.  Substitute into the power mean formula, and one gets:

$$
\left[1 + \frac p2 (\log x + \log y)\right]^{\frac1p} = \left[1 +  p \log \sqrt{xy}\right]^{\frac1p}.
$$

Let $s = \frac1p$, and this is

$$
\left[1 +  \frac{\log \sqrt{xy}}{s}\right]^s
$$

The limit of that as $s\to{+\infty}$ is

$$
e^{\log\sqrt{xy}} = \sqrt{xy}.
$$

Making this rigorous is not trivial.

Comment: Engineers are always right, for physically plausible values of "right".

Comment: The best math student will say that sin x ~~ x and thus you just get 1. And will point out equivalent infinitesimals https://math.fel.cvut.cz/en/mt/txtb/5/txe3bb5l.htm

Answer (score 7):

You can't use L'hopital in the third equality sign because you don't have a $"0/0"$ expression.

You get
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x - 2x}{4x^3 + 3x^2 + 2x}.
$$
Here the numerator approaches $1$ and the denominator approaches $0$, so in all the limit doesn't exist.

Also note that
$$
4x^3 + 3x^2 + 2x 
$$
is negative when $x <0$ and it is positive when $x>0$. Therefore one can't say that the limit is $\infty$ or $-\infty$. The limit just doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

From the second equality we find
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{e^x-2x}{4x^3+3x^2+2x}=\infty$$

thus the other equalities are false.

Comment: I don't think that the limit is $+\infty$.

Comment: The limit is $+\infty$ at $0^+$ and $-\infty$ at $0^-$.

Comment: Its not necessarily infinite; approaching from the right and left yield different values.

Comment: @Ra1nMaster How itsn't necessary infinite? It's $\pm \infty$.

Comment: It is not infinite because the right and left limit are different. "infinity" implies positive infinity. If the limit's left and right values are different, the limit is nonexistent.

Comment: @Ra1nMaster So we agree on the result look to my comment just above  and that's exactly what I meant by writing $\infty$ without sign $\pm$.

Comment: My bad. I misunderstood your argument. The limit is, however, nonexistent. I do not believe that positive infinity can be considered negative infinity; what is the logic behind that.

Comment: @Val there is an argument, "even if" they did not. If the left and right limits are not equal (which positive infinity, as far as I know, is not the same as negative infinity), the limit is nonexistent.

Comment: Ok, but in this case limits are equal, since ∞ = 2∞ = -∞, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10124/the-factorial-of-1-2-3#comment354984_137634 (Please note how Theo Johnson-Freyd mocks my hesitation whether I should have + or - in the negative factorial). I therefore would not be as cathegorical as you.

Answer (score 1):

L'Hôpital's rule is ment to applied only when you have to limit of the form 0/0. Once your limit is not in 0/0 form, you are not supposed to apply L'Hôpital's rule.

Answer (score 0):

In layman's terms:

L'Hôpital's rule should only be applied when we have the limit of the form:

0/0

Read: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LHospitalsRule.aspx
and
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/TypesOfInfinity.aspx

Another tip:

If you are using the rule and you find yourself differentiating many times then there is another way to solve these limits. Like simple reduction or change of base.